# Application won't launch from Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-launcher

I'm using my phone to test the application that I've been developing and I use android studio for building the app. When I tried to test the app on my phone, the app won't launch. But when I tried the built sample activity in the android studio it's working on my phone. I don't know how to fix this. I'm currently using Huawei Nova 3i.

PS: sorry for my bad English, English is not my mother tongue.

Comment: There's not enough information here. Check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://developer.android.com/studio/debug come back with details if you're still stuck.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I am in android like you in English, but i would try to do teess things in your situation:

1. Check android event log, need to figure out the reason of app launch crash
2. Check your build configuration in Android Studio, may be it has any sense to change dev build to release
3. Check if android emulator or project libs to be compatiable with android version

Answer (score 0):

That problem has many causes, If your module success configuration see manifest file you must make only one have launcher and delete android:name from it must launch successfully, But If your module didn't success configuration your must do it before.